Select, Filter and Sort ist not working with Oracle SQL Developer
I am using SAP ADBC to UPDATE some Oracle database entries.
It's working and the data appearance in the SQL Developer between "normal" and UPDATED entries look same.
But when I use a,
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE TIMESTAMP > 01.01.2024

it just shows me all the entries, which are not UPDATED via SAP.
Looks like the UPDATE of SAP ADBC is doing something with the written data, maybe a conversion?
I can just see the "SAP" entries, when I use a SELECT * and scroll through all available entries, which is not suitable for a large amount
Is there a way to check, what happened to the updated data?
